# Guest checkout with PayPal Express: How about the shipping costs?

Tags: shipping, paypal-express

I'm not sure whether I've understand PayPal Express completely so far.

When a guest visits a product page and clicks on the PayPal Express button (if activated), how does PayPal know how much shipping cost it has to add to the product price?

Transfers Magento the shipping rate table to PayPal?

Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you checkout with PayPal Express after signing into PayPal and selecting your payment method you get redirected back to your store to the `Review Order` page.

On the `Review Order` page *you have to* select the `Shipping Method` before placing the order. Once you select the shipping method and hit `Place Order` your PayPal totals get updated with the cost of the selected shipping method. You get charged, and the order is placed.

Comment: Don't know why but anyhow I've overseen that. Thanks!